# does clone method in C# (or in java) use new operator internally?

Tags: c#, java

This was a interview question actually, about different ways to create class instances. new and reflection are well known. But clone() also creates objects. But does it internally use new keyword to create it ? This was asked in context of c#, but would also like to know about java.

Answer (score 3):

`Clone()` in C# is implemented by implementing the `ICloneable` interface. How you do this is entirely up to you.

For instance,

- Immutable objects such as `String` and `RuntimeType` simply return `this` (i.e. themself).
- A few standard `Clone` calls (i.e. `System.Array`, `System.Delegate` return `Object.MemberwiseClone()` which does a CLR call to create a shallow copy. I imagine this is similar to `new()` (it will create new references etc.) but I don't believe (though don't have the assembly to confirm) it will invoke a constructor.
- Other objects tend to implement their own `Clone()` procedure.

Example `Clone()` method from `System.Version`

```
public object Clone()
{
    Version version = new Version();
    version._Major = this._Major;
    version._Minor = this._Minor;
    version._Build = this._Build;
    version._Revision = this._Revision;
    return version;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java, when calling `clone()` the convention is that the returned object should be obtained by calling `super.clone()`. Eventually, this gets to the [`Object`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)'s [`clone()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone) method. At this point, the behavior is determined by the [`Clonable`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) interface: if a class implements [`Clonable`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html), the [`clone()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone) method of [`Object`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) returns a **field-by-field** copy of the object; otherwise a [`CloneNotSupportedException`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/CloneNotSupportedException.html) is thrown. So `clone()` creates an object without calling a constructor, what you get is a [shallow copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_copy) of the object.

As a side note Java's `clone` is [known to be broken](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html) and Joshua Bloch recommends to  provides a **copy constructor** or **copy factory** instead. This is discussed in Effective Java 2nd Edition, [Item 11: Override clone judiciously](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Typically, `Clone` implementations would use the protected `MemberwiseClone` method to create the base object, and then tweak fields as appropriate (for instance, deep copy a list instead of having both instances reference the same one).

There's nothing that says they *have* to do this, though - they could call a constructor to generate the object and then set fields as necessary.

Internally, `MemberwiseClone` is (I think - not sure on this) just a direct transcription of the memory the object occupies, and doesn't involve the constructor in any way.

Answer (score 0):

For Java the answer is 'no'. Documentation is very specific about algorithm:

*this method creates a new instance of the class of this object and initializes all its fields with exactly the contents of the corresponding fields of this object, as if by assignment; the contents of the fields are not themselves cloned. Thus, this method performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep copy" operation.*

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()

You can easily check it in practice also.

Comment: You left out the beginning of that paragraph: 'The method clone for class Object performs a specific cloning operation'. So your quotation only applies to the implementation in java.lang.Object. What overrides in derived classes may do is completely up to them: they normally call super.clone() and then do other stuff to the result, but there's nothing to enforce that, and no statement anywhere that it's required.

Comment: @EJP You're right, but there's also a convention: _By convention, the returned object should be obtained by calling super.clone._   So, what you describe is possible, although it would be considered a 'bad java'.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the consensus is, since new involves a constructor, and clone doesn't involve calling a constructor (unless we come up with our implementation of clone), clone doesn't use new internally.

Answer (score 0):

For C# it is very easy to test what object.MemberwiseClone does in terms of constructors:

```
class Program
{
    class A : ICloneable
    {
        public int X = 2;
        public A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hiya");
            X = 1;
        }

        public object Clone()
        {
            A a = MemberwiseClone() as A;

            return a;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.X = 3;
        A b = a.Clone() as A;
    }
}
```

Put a breakpoint in the constructor. It is called once for the above program. And if you think about it Clone in a base class cannot call a constructor:

- What is it going to construct? It
  could reflect and get the most
  derived type.
- But what if that type
  doesn't have a public parameterless
  constructor?
- Can it invoke a private
  or protected constructor and expect
  the object to be initialized
  correctly.

The default implementation of MemberWiseClone has to depend on lower level type initialization and not construction. The alternative would be difficult to implement, difficult to understand and a source of hard to find bugs.